# How to find css file path in browser

Tags: css, magento2

I am working on theming part in Magento2. Whenever I compile .less file, two css files are created :

- styles-l.css
- styles-m.css

Whenever we inspect the element and try to see the css applied in the browser, we are not able to find the css file path. I mean, I cannot know from which files my css is coming from.

Is there any way to find the css file path?

Comment: Inspect in developer toolbar

Comment: have u used Firebug on firefox ?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the file : copy link adress ? (from chrome F12 Developer Tools)

[image]

It returns the absolute path.

### EDIT

You have n .css files and after compilation only 2. So, before compilation, for each of your style sheets, you can create a namespace (or a class) so you will be able to know from which file it is from.

Comment: copying link address will give path of styles-l.css

Comment: @AdityaKumar Ok now I see what you want. Why not, before compilation, for each of your style sheets, create a namespace (or a class) so you will be able to know from which file it is from ?

Comment: This can be a good suggestion. Any thing else which i can do for other parts which has already been implemented

Comment: @AdityaKumar I don't see anything else, i'm sorry. All I can advice you is to take time to reorder your files (already implemented), so you will have a more maintainable code ;) Hope I helped you.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Will try to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug extension in firfox, then inspect an element as you describe, lastly just copy either the Css Path clearly visible.

Comment: in magento2 we have n number of .less file. when we compile our less file, only two css file is generated. So it becomes very tough to find the exact css file.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using chrome to inspect, Select any element from dom, in the styles tab you can see styles applied on that element and right to that respective style sheet name > mouse over the style sheet to see the path. like :
/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css
/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-m.css

Comment: It won't help him to know from which file a part of css is from. Because from n files he only has 2 files.